# Pdf from http response not opening on browser

Tags: javascript, pdf

Servlet code:

```
response.reset();
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Cache-control", "private");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);                                
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\"test.pdf\"" );
response.setContentLength(baos.size());
ServletOutputStream os =response.getOutputStream();
baos.writeTo(os);
os.flush();
os.close();
```

Javascript client code:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
var url = "http://localhost:800/WebApplication2/JSONDecode";
var method = "POST";
var async = true;
request.open(method, url, async);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-    urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
alert(request.response);
window.open(request.response,"_blank");
}}
request.send("json=" + json);
```

Returns in an alert box:

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
1 0 obj
<</ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Subtype/Image/Height 1960/Filter/FlateDecode       /Type/XObject/Width 1040/Length 651582/BitsPerComponent 8>>stream
x���wY�������}�}o�xﵹ]Uݕ��$I �o \br ��
```

I want the browser to recognise it as a pdf.  I have looked all over but can't see what I am doing wrong.  The browser page gives a error 400 message from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, so given the problems I had thought I'd post it.  Had to use getParams to load it from a link pointing back to the pdf stream.  Seems to work well, but if anyones got a better answer.

```
var rpdf = request.response;
if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
var getParams=jQuery('#createPO').serialize();
getParams=jQuery.trim(getParams);
getParams='http://myserver.com/WebApp/Servlet?'+getParams;
document.location=getParams;}
```

Just put this into the onreadystatechange function.